# "Warning" is treated as "Error" when executing SQL, "delete from (tablename)", in Db2

Tags: node.js, docker, db2

Database server: Db2 v11.5.7.0 docker image(https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2)

Database client: node.js + node-db2 library(https://www.npmjs.com/package/db2)

I am developing web application with Node.js which use IBM Db2(docker image). Almost all operations work fine, but I am facing one strange behavior which seems to be product failure.

My code is like this. When I am trying to delete all records from table, I mean when I try to execute "delete from xxxx" SQL, operation itself would work as expected(all records would be deleted after operation), but there supposed to be a "warning" message because it operate entire table. Warning would be fine for me. But in my Node.js code, this "warning" would be handled as "error" with SQL state '01504':

```
// connection
var database_url = 'DATABASE=db;HOSTNAME=xx.xx.xx.xx;UID=user;PWD=pass;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP';
var Pool = require( 'ibm_db' ).Pool;
var pool = new Pool();
pool.init( 5, database_url );

pool.open( database_url, function( err, conn ){
  conn.query( 'delete from xxxx', [], function( err, result ){
    if( err ){
      // here
      conn.close();
      console.log( err );  //"[DataDirect][ODBC DB2 Wire Protocol driver][UDB DB2 for Windows, UNIX, and Linux]The SQL statement will modify an entire table or view."
    }else{
      // not here
        :
        :
    }
  });
}
```

I am not sure if this would be from server or client driver.
Do I miss any operational preparations? How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

it is work as design. take a look at the documentation: https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/blob/master/APIDocumentation.md

you should use the method: getSQLErrorSync, if the returned value is > 0 it is a warning and if it is < 0 it is an error:

```
conn.querySync("insert into mytab1 values ( 5, 'abc')");
  conn.prepare("select * from mytab1", function (err, stmt) {
    stmt.execute(function(err, result) {
      console.log("Fetched Data = ", result.fetchAllSync() );
      var problem = result.getSQLErrorSync();
      if (problem.sqlcode < 0) { // This sqlcode is negative and is therefore an error
        console.log("SQLError = ", problem);
      } else if (problem.sqlcode > 0) { // This sqlcode is positive and is therefore a warning
        console.log("SQLWarning = ", problem);
      }
      result.closeSync();
      conn.closeSync();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. This information helped me. In my code, I can get sqlcode from `err.sqlcode`.